# Adding custom search engines to Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, search-engines, google-search

How do I add Wikipedia and Google in the search bar in Microsoft Internet Explorer 9?

Where in the settings do I add such custom search engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE9 the link has changed to 'Find more search providers'

However this link will help you ... It contains both google and wikipedia.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/searchguide/en-en/default.mspx

**UPDATE:** Here is the new link for [google](http://www.google.com/homepage/search/).

Comment: Thank you ! This link works but this one does not : iegallery.com/fr/addons/?feature=searchproviders. There is a big problem because IE9 sent me to the last one !

Comment: And how to switch between the different search engines ?

Comment: The link you provided works fine for me.

Comment: Link no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

When you type in your search term in the address bar there should be an option at the bottom of the drop down that appears to add more search engines.

Comment: I have no such thing :-(

Comment: Sorry, just going by memory since the machine I'm on doesn't have IE9.

Comment: It used to be the case on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Either manage add-ons\search providers\ or internet options\settings (under the search line, on the general tab)

Comment: Thanks. Tools -> Manage Add-ons -> Search providers. But this page does not work : http://www.iegallery.com/fr/addons/?feature=searchproviders

Comment: See my answer above. Like i said that link doesn't work.

Comment: This is very confusing because IE9 sent me to this link. I hope Microsoft is aware of this problem.