# Quickly switch between search engines in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, search-engines

I have [added custom search engines in Internet Explorer 9](https://superuser.com/questions/292108/microsoft-internet-explorer-9-adding-search-engines) but would like to be able to switch between using them in the search bar.

How can I quickly switch between using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods:

Tools > Manage Addons > Search Providers ... and choose which search engine to set as default.

Alternatively, in the address bar you will see a small magnifying glass - When you click on it you will then see a drop down search tool with the option to switch between your installed search providers.

Comment: I have this magnifying glass, but when I click on it, nothing interesting happens.

Comment: What about the small arrow next to it?

Comment: It does not work :(

Comment: Okay goto Tools > Manage Addons > Search Providers. Click on each of your providers and Check the box that says 'Search in the address bar'

Comment: These boxes were already checked :-( I am sorry :-(

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I had deactived the "automatic data capture" (is that the right translation ?). But I cannot see why it was a problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you go to this [page](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/searchguide/en-en/default.mspx) and click on anyone of the search engine icons, that search engine will be installed.  The dialog will ask do you want to make it your default search engine.  To change your search engine, click on the option icon in the top right. Then manage add-ons and then manage search providers.  This will allow you to change the search engine.

Comment: Thank you but I want to quickly switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

TFirefox has keyword searches, where you can type "search engine" keyword. Use this for the URL:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s

The search term will replace %s.

Comment: but the question was about Internet Explorer!